codeigniter: Unable to call api folder in localhost
I am getting below error when i am trying to call the api folder
url:
localhost:82/macroflex/app/v1/api/login
Error
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

    Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.1.25 Server at localhost Port 82

The error says it all: your api folder is not found inside v1. So it's either missing or your OS user that is using the webserver does not have access privileges over it. To solve the issue, create the folder if it did not exist and make sure your OS user has the necessary privileges.
